# Cross-reference a single word in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I would like to cross-reference a single word/series of words, for my abbreviation list.

Ie, in the document:

> **Section Header 1.2**
>
> *Sub Header 1.2.4*
>
> This is Microsoft Word 2013 (MW13)

I want to now cross-reference MW13, such as:

```
Abbreviation    Meaning                          Location
MW13            Microsoft Word 2013              Section 1.2.4, P12
```

Where the 1.2.4 and 12 are the cross-references required. Is this, or a similar function, possible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want your abbreviation list sorted alphabetically, the closest you can *easily* get to this is to use { XE } fields and an INDEX field. But to get a tabular layout in the list of abbreviations you would have to use a "placeholder" string in place of each tab, then replace that after you have generated the INDEX. Further, in each XE you would have to specify the style you wanted the Section number to come from, if that needs to be variable.

There are actually various different ways you could construct the fields. Below is one, where you insert the page number in the XE entries - you could do that in the INDEX field instead)

So, taking your example, in your text you could write

```
This is Microsoft Word 2013 (MW13){ XE "MW13@@Microsoft Word 2013" \t "Section { STYLEREF "the style name of your sub header paragraph" \r }, P{ PAGE }" \fx }
```

In the above, *every* pair of { } needs to be a pair of the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word.

Your INDEX field could then be like this:

```
{ INDEX \fx \e "<tab>" \r }
```

Where you would actually insert a tab character where I have put ""

You would need to put a header row above your Index field, with "AbbreviationMeaningLocation

After selecting all the field codes and using F9 to update them you would probably have an index that looked like this:

MW13@@Microsoft Word 2013.......................Section 1.2.4, P12

You would then have to select that index, replace @@ by a tab, and fix the tab positions, leaders and types (perhaps using VBA).

Another thing you will need to avoid to make this work is putting a colon ":" character in your XE text (try it and you will see what happens!)

This would be a lot easier if Word preserved the tabs you put in your XE text, but it doesn't.